# DataURL needs to be converted in Image and image needs to be cropped and saved into multiple images?

Tags: angular, typescript, crop, drawimage

I am new to angular. I've a scenario where I am getting a DataURL which needs to converted into image and without saving that image I've to crop or split that image into different images from a particular y position.

I've tried using drawImage() but still not able to achieve the desired output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be below link help you.https://betterprogramming.pub/convert-a-base64-url-to-image-file-in-angular-4-5796a19fdc21

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.